# Samsung Galaxy S stuck in boot loop when 100% charged

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, charging, boot, boot-loop

Before we start I should mention that I have not messed with the firmware in any way. But it seems that whenever I put it on charge and it reaches 100% capacity I turn it on and it gets stuck in a boot loop. I have turned it off and on while it hasn't been on charge and it worked fine.

This happened once and I wiped all user data from the phone and it fixed it. But it's doing it again and I have tried looking around on Google but I cannot find a solution at all.